# Deluge WebUI, adding torrents with different download directory and label

Tags: bittorrent, deluge

So deluge doesn't  natively support adding a torrent with a different label or download directory than the global set one. So the browser addons available dont either. So i worked out a way to get around this for adding torrents to the webui without writing a custom plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How it works is by directing the output of the browser addon to the below php script instead of deluge itself. The scrip then saves the torrent or magnet to a specific watch directory specified by a paramater in the addon url. From here the "AutoAdd" plugin for deluge will be set up to monitor the various watch directories you want and load torrents from each with a chosen label, and download directory (orany other setting available by that addon) specific to that watch directory.

```
    <?php

    //specify hostname in addon as server.com/thisScript.php?label=labelName
    //tested with these addons:
    //https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/bittorrent-webui-120685/
    //https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/remote-torrent-adder/oabphaconndgibllomdcjbfdghcmenci?hl=en
    //in deluge mode, others may work.
    //specify server address as server.com/path/storeTorrent.php?label=labelname
    //label folder must first be created
    //use with AutoAdd plugin, to watch directories, and add with individual labels and locations
    //http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/Plugins/AutoAdd (configure with pc client)
    //edit $watchDir to your base watch dir yours

    $watchDir = '/media/sdf1/home/private/deluge/watch/';

    $label = str_replace(array("json",":"),"",$_REQUEST['label']);

    //file_put_contents('debug.txt', json_encode($_REQUEST).'--'.file_get_contents('php://input'));//debug full
    //file_put_contents('debug.txt', $label;//debug just label param

    if($label && is_dir($watchDir.$label)){
                $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
                $array = json_decode($json,true);

                if($array['method'] == 'core.add_torrent_magnet'){
                    preg_match('#magnet:\?xt=urn:btih:(?<hash>.*?)&dn=(?<filename>.*?)&tr=(?<trackers>.*?)$#', $array['params'][0], $magnet_link);
                    file_put_contents($watchDir.$label.$magnet_link['hash'].'.magnet', $array['params'][0]);
                }else if($array['method'] == 'core.add_torrent_file'){              
                    file_put_contents( $watchDir.$label.md5($array['params'][1]).'.torrent' , base64_decode($array['params'][1]));
                }


    }
    else header(':', true, 401);


    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo '{"id": 0, "result": true, "error": null}';
    ?>
```

http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/Plugins/AutoAdd
[image]